# Badge progress counts not updating

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

My [Illuminator badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/68258#68258) progress counts are not updating for about a week now, I believe. Maybe more.

Does something need fixing?

Comment: well I thought I knew how it works. apparently I was mistaken. apologies, and thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I found:

- Your current progress is 345.
- According to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1425251/1751610/illuminator-badge-progress-test-for-showing-the-question-link-where-earned-credi), you should have 344 eligible answers until last Sunday (SEDE is updated on Sunday).
- According to the same query, the most recent eligible answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67999270/8967612).
- You have posted 9 answers after that one. However, you've only edited the parent question of only four of them. Three of which are not eligible because you only edited the tags. That leaves only one [additional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68054488) to be added to the 344 ones returned by the query.
- 344 + 1 = 345 ;)

Therefore, the current progress appears to be accurate.

Comment: my bad. forgot about the tag-only editing.  thanks! I've just made [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68074633/revisions) to a question to which I've answered 11 hours ago; we'll see if and when the count updates.